# How to mock in-place arithmetic operators

Tags: python, mocking

I'm trying to mock the in-place operators' magic methods like `__iadd__` with `MagicMock` from `unittest.mock`, but the call assertion unexpectedly fails:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> m = MagicMock()
>>> m += 1
>>> m.__iadd__.assert_called_once()  # This expected NOT to fail
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AssertionError: Expected '__iadd__' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
```

Mocking other magic methods works fine:

```
>>> m = MagicMock()
>>> m + 1
>>> m.__add__.assert_called_once()
>>> # No error
```

After doing `m += 1` sets `m` to a new `MagicMock` instance since all mock methods return new mocks. We override `__iadd__` in regular classes like this:

```
class A:
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        ...
        return self  # <-- We must return self
```

But all mock's methods including `__iadd__` looks like:

```
def __iadd__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    return MagicMock()
```

In my opinion that's the reason why it fails.

---

So, how do I properly mock in-place arithmetic magic methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the return value of `__iadd__` like this:

```
>>> m = MagicMock()
>>> m.__iadd__.return_value = m
>>> m += 1
>>> m.__iadd__.assert_called_once()
>>> m.__iadd__.call_count
1
```

Comment: Just thought that it's worth mentioning that a lot of tutorials say when in doubt just use `Mock`. This is a case where `Mock` won't cut it. You must use `MagicMock` to override the magic method `__iadd__`.